# How to make VideoJS with HLS plugin buffers on pause

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I'm using **VideoJS 5.10.2** with **VideoJS-contrib-hls-3.10** to stream encrypted HLS videos. And they work fine, except on slow connection, the video often stops (because it's waiting for the next chunk being downloaded). It really is a bad experience for clients.

So I'm wondering if there is any way to **let VideoJS buffers while video is paused**, so clients can playback smoothly after pausing the video for a while.

I've searched high and low for the setup-options to achieve this, but couldn't find any light.

I know **Viblast Player** has this ability using "**buffer-while-paused**" and "**low-buffer-level**" options. (I refrain from using viblast player because the js filesize is almost 2MB. Even more problem to my clients)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you looked at creating a bitrate that's suitable for slower connections? the point of HLS is the stream will try to always play by adapting to a lower quality set of fragments. if you want to buffer in order to maintain quality then you may be better off with a non-fragmented mp4 (but then encryption becomes a challenge)

Comment: yes I created ABR playlist with 4 qualities 240p 360p 480p 720p but still not smooth enough for them. and yes i really need the encryption.

Comment: wow, how poor is the data connection? I've not seen a "buffer while paused" equivalent on a lightwight HLS library, it's not normally how HLS would work. Good luck with the search

Comment: Mostly used on mobile connection with speed around 100-300kbps. Thanks for the replies